# Find where RUNTIME annotation is processed by 3rd party library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

I often find myself trying to figure out how a particular annotation works under the hood.  Performing a 'find usages' on the annotation in the IDE(like IntelliJ) will usually just bring you to where the annotation is actually used.  I don't see an easy way however of finding the logic that processes the annotation.

I get that because of the nature of annotations that it's difficult to see where they are being processed, but at the same time, when they are consumed one would have had to import the specific annotation so there is a link established.

Take the case of

SomeAnnotation.java

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
}
```

and it's being consumed in AnnotationConsumer.java

```
import com.annotations.SomeAnnotation
public class AnnotationProcessor {

  public AnnotationProcessor() {
    if (currentClass.isAnnotationPresent(SomeAnnotation.class)) {
      // do some logic
    }
  }
}
```

Usually, some piece of code will be tagged with @SomeAnnotation.

What I would like to do is find the AnnotationProcessor class where SomeAnnotation is being processed.

Anything I've searched for so far simply leads me down a path of HOW to process annotations, not WHERE they are being processed.

Comment: If "find usages" doesn't help you should be able to at least search for `SomeAnnotation.class` directly which should normally bring up the places where it is being processed.

Comment: usage at runtime?

Comment: Thanks, but Searching for SomeAnnotation.class will only work if there is nothing else in your code called SomeAnnotation.  This usually isn't the case in large projects.  Also, if the annotation you are using is coming from an external library I don't believe a simple 'text search' will find it.  Take the case for example of Lombok's '@Getter' annotation.  A search for 'Getter.class' won't find any results, even when set to search in All Places.  Find Usages will only show you where @Getter is used and searching for 'Getter' could find all sorts of things in a large project.

Comment: sorry, I've updated title to reflect Runtime usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about runtime annotation processor, then debug the application in IDEA, put a conditional break point on `Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class<? extends Annotation> a)` method.

condition is `a.equals(SomeAnnotation.class)`.

debug will be slow because of conditional break point, but you may find out the call stack when break point hit.

Comment: Not a bad idea, thanks.  I guess it would work, but it's a bit tedious when you're just browsing the code to have to do this each time.

Comment: then it is simple, you should have source attached for library jars, then do a "find usage" for the  SomeAnnotation class with the scope "Project and libraries"

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I'm looking at decompiled class files for the libraries (with no source attached, and that is why the IDE can't find any usages.  Will try your suggestion to attach source first, thanks)

Comment: Attaching the source solved the issue.  IDE now lists the usage under the .class 'find usages' category. Thanks!

Comment: The only downside is that if you are pulling in 100's of libraries it's challenging to find all the places where it's consumed and attach the source for each.  Not much you can do though I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I think the root cause of my problem was probably more related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193746/how-to-search-string-in-decompiled-class-files-in-intellij

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether you are thinking of compile-time annotation processing or run-time annotation processing.

For compile-time annotation processing, the annotation processor is either listed on the command line after a `-processor` flag, or (for automatic discovery) it is listed in a file named `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` that is on the search path.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html .

Comment: sorry, I've updated title to reflect Runtime usage.